# Why does SpringBootTest ComponentScan finds a bean outside of the basePackages and tries to create it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, component-scan

I have a `@SpringBootTest` that use a `@Configuration` class with `@ComponentScan`:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = BaseTest.Conf.class)
public class SocGenTest extends BaseTest {
```

And the configuration class:

```
public class BaseTest {

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {
            "com.capitolis.novation",
            "com.capitolis.generated",
            "com.capitolis.trade"
    },
    excludeFilters = {
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com.capitolis.trade.resolve.clients.*")
    })
    public static class Conf {

    }
```

But when I run the test it complains about a missing dependency for a component that is not in one of the scanned packages and shouldn't be created at all:

```
UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pageReplacerModelConverter'
```

This class is in another package:

```
package com.capitolis.springboot.openapi;

@Component
public class PageReplacerModelConverter extends AbstractModelConverter {
```

- Anybody knows of a reason this component is being created?
- Is there some other thing in my project that may cause my test to try load things from outside of the packages I defined?
- Is there a way to turn on tracing of the component scan so I can maybe understand why it is trying to create this component?

Thank you

Comment: Is the bean part of a component u scanned?

Comment: @NicoS. Do you mean a dependency of a component I scan or a return value of a `@Bean` method?

Comment: i mean a dependency of a component you scan. Do you use intellij ultimate ?

Comment: @NicoS. As far as I know, it is not a dependency of any of my components (but maybe I'm and there is some path to it). If it is a dependency of a component I would expect to see a missing dependency error and not that it will just try to create it